# How to delete 3 consecutive rows that contain the same value in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table in R with 3 features as follow

```
DT_A <- data.table(sid=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,3), date=as.Date(c("2014-06-22","2014-06-23","2014-06-22","2014-06-23", "2014-06-24","2014-06-22",
                                                          "2014-06-23","2014-06-24","2014-06-25","2014-06-26")), 
               Status1 = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","A","A","B","B"))
```

The data looks like this

```
    sid       date Status1
 1:   1 2014-06-22       A
 2:   1 2014-06-23       B
 3:   2 2014-06-22       A
 4:   2 2014-06-23       A
 5:   2 2014-06-24       B
 6:   3 2014-06-22       A
 7:   3 2014-06-23       A
 8:   2 2014-06-24       A
 9:   3 2014-06-25       B
10:   3 2014-06-26       B
```

How can i check the Status 1 and see if there are 3 rows in a row that has value A (like row 6,7,8) then we will delete these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is tagged `data.table`, so I'll try to give an appropriate answer:

```
DT_A[!DT_A[, .I[.N == 3 & Status1 == "A"], by = rleid(Status1)]$V1]
```

> ```
>      sid       date Status1
> 1:     1 2014-06-22       A
> 2:     1 2014-06-23       B
> 3:     2 2014-06-22       A
> 4:     2 2014-06-23       A
> 5:     2 2014-06-24       B
> 6:     3 2014-06-25       B
> 7:     3 2014-06-26       B
> ```

#### Other test cases

As pointed out by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161795/how-to-delete-3-consecutive-rows-that-contain-the-same-value-in-a-data-table/47162738?noredirect=1#comment81279807_47162738), my first answer (now edited) was working *just for the given sample data set* provided by the OP but failed for other test cases.

So, the edited code is applied to some other test cases.

**Case B:** 3 consecutive rows of letters `A` and `B`

```
DT_B <- data.table(
  sid=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3), 
  date=as.Date(c("2014-06-22","2014-06-23","2014-06-22","2014-06-23", "2014-06-24","2014-06-22",
                 "2014-06-23","2014-06-24","2014-06-25","2014-06-26","2014-06-26")), 
  Status1 = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","A","A","B","B","B"))
DT_B
```

> ```
>     sid       date Status1
>  1:   1 2014-06-22       A
>  2:   1 2014-06-23       B
>  3:   2 2014-06-22       A
>  4:   2 2014-06-23       A
>  5:   2 2014-06-24       B
>  6:   3 2014-06-22       A
>  7:   3 2014-06-23       A
>  8:   2 2014-06-24       A
>  9:   3 2014-06-25       B
> 10:   3 2014-06-26       B
> 11:   3 2014-06-26       B
> ```

```
DT_B[!DT_B[, .I[.N == 3 & Status1 == "A"], by = rleid(Status1)]$V1]
```

> ```
>    sid       date Status1
> 1:   1 2014-06-22       A
> 2:   1 2014-06-23       B
> 3:   2 2014-06-22       A
> 4:   2 2014-06-23       A
> 5:   2 2014-06-24       B
> 6:   3 2014-06-25       B
> 7:   3 2014-06-26       B
> 8:   3 2014-06-26       B
> ```

Only the 3 consecutive rows containing letter `A` (rows 6 to 8) are removed.

**Case C:** Nothing to remove

```
DT_C <- data.table(
  sid=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3), 
  date=as.Date(c("2014-06-22","2014-06-23","2014-06-22","2014-06-23", "2014-06-24","2014-06-22",
                 "2014-06-23","2014-06-24","2014-06-25","2014-06-26","2014-06-26")), 
  Status1 = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","A","C","B","B","C"))
DT_C
```

> ```
>     sid       date Status1
>  1:   1 2014-06-22       A
>  2:   1 2014-06-23       B
>  3:   2 2014-06-22       A
>  4:   2 2014-06-23       A
>  5:   2 2014-06-24       B
>  6:   3 2014-06-22       A
>  7:   3 2014-06-23       A
>  8:   2 2014-06-24       C
>  9:   3 2014-06-25       B
> 10:   3 2014-06-26       B
> 11:   3 2014-06-26       C
> ```

```
DT_C[!DT_C[, .I[.N == 3 & Status1 == "A"], by = rleid(Status1)]$V1]
```

> ```
>     sid       date Status1
>  1:   1 2014-06-22       A
>  2:   1 2014-06-23       B
>  3:   2 2014-06-22       A
>  4:   2 2014-06-23       A
>  5:   2 2014-06-24       B
>  6:   3 2014-06-22       A
>  7:   3 2014-06-23       A
>  8:   2 2014-06-24       C
>  9:   3 2014-06-25       B
> 10:   3 2014-06-26       B
> 11:   3 2014-06-26       C
> ```

No row is removed as there are no 3 consecutive rows containing `A`.

**Case D:** Edge case: remove all rows

```
DT_D <- DT_A[6:8]
DT_D
```

> ```
>    sid       date Status1
> 1:   3 2014-06-22       A
> 2:   3 2014-06-23       A
> 3:   2 2014-06-24       A
> ```

```
DT_D[!DT_D[, .I[.N == 3 & Status1 == "A"], by = rleid(Status1)]$V1]
```

> ```
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: sid,date,Status1
> ```

All rows are removed and an empty data.table is returned because the input data.table consists only of 3 rows with letter `A`.

Comment: You need to check that x in rleid(x) evaluates to TRUE in addition to that .N == 3 (or perhaps .N >= 3). Also x[-w] is a bad idea, since when w = integer(0), the result is like x[0]. I'd maybe do `DT_A[, keep := !(.N >= 3L && Status1 == "A"), by=rleid(Status1)][(keep), !"keep"]` or something. Fwiw, db's answer also has the first problem (checking length of the rle(x) group without verify that x is true there).

Comment: Thank you, @Frank for pointing out the flaws. Fixed and other test cases added.

Answer (score 1):

```
with(rle(DT_A$Status1 == "A"), {
    unlist(lapply(which(lengths >= 3), function(i)
        (1+cumsum(lengths)[i-1]):cumsum(lengths)[i]))
})
#[1] 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing you are making a mistake in your sid definition, and that your 3 lines have all sid = 3. If not, sorry my answer will not work. If it is the case the solution can be one line:

```
 DT_A[,.SD[.N < 3 | Status1 != "A",], by = .(sid,Status1)]
```

Is a simple line that does what you want : it select the data where the number of line is less than 3 or different than B in column Status1 (that is the negation of your selection you want to make to delete : at least 3 A) when grouping by sid and Status1.
Hope it helps

Comment: This answer will remove also *non-consecutive* rows.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for the remark. You are totally wright. I learned something with your answer with rleid.  And actually my condition .N<3 is not totally correct either as the question is for 3 rows in a row.
Thanks again, sorry for the mistake